# how to add extra column that counts the occurance of each character in a cellarray using matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to write a code that it add extra column for the number of occurance of the characters in each cell for the fourth column for the cellarray GO :

```
GO:
      'GO:0008150'    [1]    [1]    'a'
      'GO:0016740'    [2]    [2]    'b'
      'GO:0006412'    [2]    [2]    'b'
      'GO:0016787'    [2]    [3]    'c'
      'GO:0006810'    [2]    [4]    'd'
      'GO:0016787'    [3]    [3]    'c'
      'GO:0004672'    [3]    [3]    'c'
      'GO:0016779'    [3]    [3]    'c'
      'GO:0005215'    [3]    [3]    'c'
      'GO:0006810'    [3]    [4]    'd'
      'GO:0004386'    [3]    [4]    'd'
      'GO:0003774'    [3]    [4]    'd'
      'GO:0016298'    [3]    [4]    'd'
      'GO:0016192'    [3]    [5]    'e'
      'GO:0006412'    [3]    [2]    'b'
      'GO:0005215'    [3]    [3]    'c'
      'GO:0006810'    [4]    [4]    'd'
      'GO:0004386'    [4]    [4]    'd'
      'GO:0003774'    [4]    [4]    'd'
      'GO:0016298'    [4]    [4]    'd'
      'GO:0030533'    [4]    [4]    'd'
      'GO:0030533'    [4]    [4]    'd'
      'GO:0016192'    [4]    [5]    'e'
```

The resulted GO cellarray should be as follows (starting from 0 value):

```
GO:     
  'GO:0008150'    [1]    [1]    'a'   '0'
  'GO:0016740'    [2]    [2]    'b'   '0'
  'GO:0006412'    [2]    [2]    'b'   '1'
  'GO:0016787'    [2]    [3]    'c'   '0'
  'GO:0006810'    [2]    [4]    'd'   '0'
  'GO:0016787'    [3]    [3]    'c'   '1'
  'GO:0004672'    [3]    [3]    'c'   '2'
  'GO:0016779'    [3]    [3]    'c'   '3'
  'GO:0005215'    [3]    [3]    'c'   '4'
  'GO:0006810'    [3]    [4]    'd'   '1'
  'GO:0004386'    [3]    [4]    'd'   '2'
  'GO:0003774'    [3]    [4]    'd'   '3'
  'GO:0016298'    [3]    [4]    'd'   '4'
  'GO:0016192'    [3]    [5]    'e'   '0'
  'GO:0006412'    [3]    [2]    'b'   '2'
  'GO:0005215'    [3]    [3]    'c'   '5'
  'GO:0006810'    [4]    [4]    'd'   '5'
  'GO:0004386'    [4]    [4]    'd'   '6'
```

I tried the following code but it doesn't work anyway:

```
x3=[];  % for saving the resulted numbers 
z=0:length(GO);  % will take the numbers from this matrix
z=z';
 for j=1:length(num2alph)
     for k=1:length(GO)
 for i=1:length(GO)
         if isequal(GO{i,4},num2alph{j})
                   x3{i}=z(k);
    else
     end
     end
     end
 end
   x3=x3';
   GO1=[GO x3];
```

where cellarray num2alph (which will compare it with the fourth column of GO array to build the numering column)is:

```
  'a'          
  'b'        
  'c'    
  'd'   
  'e'    
  'f'    
  'g'   
  'h'   
  'i'    
  'j'    
  'k'
```

also I need to map the last 2 columns with each other to be in the same cell , for example:

```
         'a'   '0'  ===>  a0
         'b'   '2'  ===>  b2
```

any advice

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
un = unique(GO(:,4));

results = zeros(size(GO(:,4)));
for ii = 1:numel(un)

    inds = strcmp(GO(:,4), un(ii));
    count = max(0, cumsum(inds)-1);

    results(inds) = count(inds);
end


GO = [GO  num2cell(results)]
```

Answer (score 2):

[`cellhist`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23933-cellhist), an user defined function, can really be your friend here. It seems to fix exactly  your needs.